# How to change webpacker in Rails to watch for changes outside of packs folder?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, webpacker

I want hot module reload to reload changes in my JavaScript/React files

I was going through [webpacker development documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development)

In that it says

> This process will watch for changes in the app/javascript/packs/*.js

Now, I want to watch for changes outside of the packs project as well or in the entire `javascript` folder and also need to include `.jsx` file.

I am not sure how I can do it.

This is my `webpacker` file:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
ENV['NODE_ENV']  ||= 'development'

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile',
                                           Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'bundler/setup'

require 'webpacker'
require 'webpacker/webpack_runner'

APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  Webpacker::WebpackRunner.run(ARGV)
end
```

And this is my webpacker dev server file

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
ENV['NODE_ENV']  ||= 'development'

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile',
                                           Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'bundler/setup'

require 'webpacker'
require 'webpacker/dev_server_runner'

APP_ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __dir__)
Dir.chdir(APP_ROOT) do
  Webpacker::DevServerRunner.run(ARGV)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I not sure that I completely understand you question, but I was stuck with problem that default rails webpack server rebuild each `.js(x)` files changes and that took long time in development. I solved it by use `gem foreman`

1. Install [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)
2. Create `Procfile.dev` in project root

```
web: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
webpacker: ruby ./bin/webpack-dev-server
```

3. my webpack-dev-server

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
ENV["NODE_ENV"]  ||= ENV["NODE_ENV"] || "development"

require "pathname"
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

require "webpacker"
require "webpacker/dev_server_runner"
Webpacker::DevServerRunner.run(ARGV)
```

4. And run project with foreman
   `foreman start -f Procfile.dev -p 3000`

After that - webpack do not build each changes and take less time to reload code changes

Also you can update your `webpacker.yml`

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: 'packs'
  public_output_path: 'packs'
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  resolved_paths: ['app/javascript/src']

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  extensions:
    - .jsx
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: /node_modules/


production:
  <<: *default
  public_path: <%= ENV['ACTION_CONTROLLER_ASSET_HOST'] %>

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```